# sony Remote API actTakePicture Original Size

Tags: sony, remoteapi

I'm using the remote API with a Alph 7R camera. I have a problem to get an Image in original size. The camera stores the image on memory card before I get the answer with the download address. This takes several seconds. When I use the camera without a memory card I get an error when I use the setPostviewImageSize command and I get in´the images in 2M size. I've tried to remove the memory card after setting the image size and that works fine. the image is displayed in less than 2s But after a reboot of the camera all settings are gone. The question is, is there a possibillity to change the image size to original without using a memory card or can I switch of storing images on memory card?

Comment: Provide code - what language are you using the API in, what have you tried etc.

Answer (score 0):

I had a bug in my code so I got the wrong image after removing the memory card. So I never get an image in Original size without a card.

I'm using c++. After getting the scalarwebapi_dd.xml I send the first command startRecMode. This works as expected. The command getAvailableApiList returns an array with all functions I can use now and including setPostviewImageSize. Is a memory card inserted into the camera, the call of setPostviewImageSize returns a string like this {"result":[0],"id":1}. If I try calling this command without a card I get a JSON string with an error like this {"id":1,"error":[1,"Failed: couldn't set postview size."]} My question is, is there a possibility to set the image size via another command or can I use actProcessImage without storing the image on a memory card.

Comment: First change the camera function to "remote control" with "startRecMode", then you can try to do getPostviewImageSize().  See the introduction from the document: When the client switches "Remote Shooting" to "Contents Transfer" via this API and switching is done successfully, the server status will change as follows.
Camera status : "IDLE" -> "ContentsTransfer"
The client should check the parameter "cameraStatus" of "getEvent" to get the camera status. The client should run initial sequence for transferring images after switching to "ContentsTransfer" status...